# Lost root access partially. Help?

Tags: permissions, root

[image: screenshot]
(Note the downloads icon. I indicates locked, whereas others arent)

I was able to access everything on my ubuntu. Last changes I made was installing Oracle java 8 and Eclipse Luna.For installing Eclipse, I followed the tutorial by Brian Gorman from Infinite skills. 
I guess the chown command i used for installing is what created the mess.

> faiz@FZ:~$ sudo su -c "chown -R root:root /home/faiz/Downloads && mv
>   /home/faiz/Downloads/eclipse /opt/eclipse-luna"

after which I suspended my laptop and after reopening, I can't change the background of my terminal, neither can i access the files in downloads. My root access is gone. But i can access my files in 'pictures' or 'videos'. Here is what I get when I try to open files in downloads folder: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnhWx.png

I opened ubuntu in recovery mode and tried adding myself as root (following this guide http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo ) It said I already have root access. But still i can't read write anything in my downloads folder. What is happening? How can I regain complete root access?

Updates: on running

```
faiz@FZ:~$ stat --format '%a' Downloads
755

faiz@FZ:~$ ls downloads
ls: cannot access downloads: No such file or directory
```

pressed alt+ctrl+f1 and typed

```
ls downloads 
ls: cannot access downloads: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Cant access the image. Please edit the link - preferably upload to http://imgur.com

Comment: I reuploaded it on imgur.com for you. Here is the link http://i.imgur.com/2OCX7O0.png

Comment: Okay, right can you [edit] to include the output of this command: `stat --format '%a' Downloads`

Comment: @Tim it gave 755 as output

Comment: Thanks. Thats odd because that's what I get. What about the first 5 lines of `ls Downloads`?

Comment: @tim 
faiz@FZ:~$ ls downloads
ls: cannot access downloads: No such file or directory

Comment: What is your username?

Comment: @tim my username is 'faiz'

Comment: If you press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login then try `ls Downloads`, can you access it? Then try running the `startx` command.

Comment: @tim 
nopes. Still can't access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `chown -R root:root /home/faiz/Downloads` will change ownership for all files and folders in Downloads. root is the new owner, so you're no longer allowed to access it.

You can change it back using this command `sudo chown -R faiz:faiz ~/Downloads`, given that your username is faiz.

Comment: Thanks !It solved my problem. I am new to linux and not at all familiar with the commands. I followed everything he said in tutorial without much thinking lol.

Comment: You're welcome. You were given the wrong command. Only Downloads/eclipse should've received new ownership, not your entire Downloads. Also, be advised Ubuntu and GNU+Linux in general, is case-sensitive. That means "downloads" and "Downloads" are not the same. That's why you got a "no such file or directory" response.